# Template not updating after model.save()

Tags: ember.js

I'm working on a form using the Ember-Data Fixture adapter. My save method is in the edit route as follows:

```
actions: {
    save: function () {
        var visit = this.get('currentModel'),
            self = this,
            store = this.store;

        visit.setProperties({
            'notes': $('#notes textarea').val()
        });

        console.log('Visit Changes: ' + visit.changedAttributes());

        visit.save();

        console.log('Visit saved!');

        self.transitionTo('planning.visits.visit', visit);
}
```

The `notes` field is referenced in the template simply as `{{notes}}` and is in the model as a `DS.attr('string')`

`visit.changedAttributes()` shows that the notes value changed and if I throw a breakpoint on the `afterModel` hook in the `planning.visits.visit` route I can get the object and see that the field was updated but the template itself never updates to reflect the change.

What am I missing?

***** EDIT *****

The view template is

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="panel-title">
            <span style="font-weight: normal; color: #666;">Visit  </span>{{visitNumber}}
        </span>
        <span class="pull-right">
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Options
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg"></i>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                <li>{{#link-to 'planning.visits.edit' this}}<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i><span style="padding-left: 10px;">Edit Visit</span>{{/link-to}}</li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span style="padding-left: 10px;">Add Tasks</span></a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a {{action 'delete'}}><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i><span style="padding-left: 10px;">Delete Visit</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>
                    <label>Date:</label><br />
                    <strong class="value">{{startDate}}</strong> to <strong class="value">{{endDate}}</strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p>
                    <label>Notes:</label><br />
                    <strong class="value">{{notes}}</strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <ul id="detail-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    {{#link-to 'planning.visits.visit.tasks' this tagName="li"}}{{#link-to 'planning.visits.visit.tasks' this}}Tasks{{/link-to}}{{/link-to}}
                    {{#link-to 'planning.visits.visit.requirements' this tagName="li"}}{{#link-to 'planning.visits.visit.requirements' this}}Requirements{{/link-to}}{{/link-to}}
                    {{#if hasIssue}}
                        {{#link-to 'planning.visits.visit.issues' this tagName="li"}}{{#link-to 'planning.visits.visit.issues' this}}Problems<span style="margin-left: 10px;>" class="badge pull-right alert-danger">1</span{{/    link-to}}{{/link-to}}    
                    {{/if}}    
                </ul>    
            </div>    
        </div>    
        <div class="row">    
            <div id="tab-content" class="col-lg-12">    
                {{outlet tabs}}    
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

And the edit template is

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="panel-title">
            <span style="font-weight: normal; color: #666;">Edit Visit </span>{{visitNumber}}
        </span>
        <span class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-default" {{action 'save'}}>
                <i class="fa fa-check green" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Save Changes
            </button>
            {{#link-to 'planning.visits.visit' this tagName="button" classNames="btn btn-default"}}
                <i class="fa fa-ban red" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Discard Changes
            {{/link-to}}
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p>             
                    {{date-picker-with-label label="Start Date" value=startDate id="startDate"}}
                </p>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p>
                    {{date-picker-with-label label="End Date" value=endDate id="endDate"}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p>
                    <label>Notes:</label>
                    {{textarea property=notes rows=3 id="notes"}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this ? http://dpaste.com/2YJK08M

Comment: Can you post the template as well? Also, a JSBin that reproduces the issue would help a lot.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using jQuery to get the value of the textarea? Normally with Ember you should take advantage of the built in data bindings along with the the text input helper as shown in this example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dabah/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @kristjanreinhold I tried your example of putting the transition inside a `then` and it still did not work.

Comment: @GJK editing OP to add the templates. Will post a link to a JSBin soon.

Comment: @EricKelly The example I was following on forms in Ember used jQuery. I tried to access the textarea via `this.get('textAreaValue')` and kept getting an `undefined`

Comment: @ultimatemonty You can answer your own question.  Please add an answer to your question.  You can accept your answer after a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. PEBKAC error on my end. Helps if both the template field and the field you are updating are the same.